# Error in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I am trying to make a ggplot. When I had shape in aesthetics, the code was working just fine. However, I need to put shape in geom_point() because I'm trying to reproduce a figure. And when I added shape to geom_point() it gave me the following error:

**Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): shape**

I've looked for other answers here but apparently, nothing seems to be working for me. Above I've provided with an image of what my data looks like. There are 17000 entries.

Below is my code:

```
summarised_data <-ddply(mammals,c('mammals$chr','mammals$Species','mammals$chrMark'), 
function (x) c(median_rpkm = median(x$RPKM), median = median(x$dNdS)))

ggplot(summarised_data,aes(x = summarised_data$median_rpkm, y = summarised_data$median, 
color = summarised_data$`mammals$Species`)) + geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
geom_point(shape = summarised_data$`mammals$chrMark`) + xlab("median RPKM") + ylab("dNdS")

  "ENSG00000213221", "ENSG00000213341", "ENSG00000213380", "ENSG00000213424", 
   "ENSG00000213533", "ENSG00000213551", "ENSG00000213619", "ENSG00000213626", 
  "ENSG00000213699", "ENSG00000213782", "ENSG00000213949", "ENSG00000214013", 
   "ENSG00000214338", "ENSG00000214357", "ENSG00000214367", "ENSG00000214517", 
    "ENSG00000214814", "ENSG00000215203", "ENSG00000215305",      "ENSG00000215367", 
   "ENSG00000215440", "ENSG00000215897", "ENSG00000221947", "ENSG00000222011", 
   "ENSG00000224051", "ENSG00000225830", "ENSG00000225921", "ENSG00000239305", 
   "ENSG00000239474", "ENSG00000239900", "ENSG00000241058", "ENSG00000242247", 
   "ENSG00000242612", "ENSG00000243646", "ENSG00000244038", "ENSG00000244045"), 
  class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Chimp", "Gori", "Human", "Maca", 
    "Mouse", "Oran"), class = "factor"), labs = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Chimp-A", "Chimp-X", 
    "Gori-A", "Gori-X", "Human-A", "Human-X", "Maca-A", "Maca-X", 
    "Mouse-A", "Mouse-X", "Oran-A", "Oran-X"), class = "factor"), 
     chrMark = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
      2L), .Label = c("A", "X"), class = "factor"), chr = structure(c(27L, 
      27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L), .Label = c("1", 
      "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
      "2", "20", "21", "22", "2a", "2A", "2b", "2B", "3", "4", 
        "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "X"), class = "factor"), dN = c(3.00669, 
       3.27182, 7.02044, 1.01784, 3.0363, 2.32786, 4.92959, 3.03753, 
       3.0776, 1.02147), dS = c(3.15631, 5.87147, 3.13716, 2.05438, 
       4.10205, 5.24764, 4.2014, 3.18086, 5.4942, 3.02169), dNdS = c(0.9525965447, 
     0.5572403504, 2.2378329444, 0.4954487485, 0.7401908802, 0.4436013141, 
1.1733207978, 0.954939859, 0.5601543446, 0.3380459279), RPKM = c(31.6, 
13.9, 26.3, 9.02, 11.3, 137, 242, 1.05, 59.4, 10.1), Tau = c(0.7113820598, 
0.8391023102, 0.3185943152, 0.6887167806, 0.9120531859, 0.6254200542, 
0.7165302682, 0.7257435312, 0.2586613298, 0.6493567251), 
GC3 = c(0.615502, 0.622543, 0.393064, 0.490141, 0.461592, 
0.626407, 0.490305, 0.482853, 0.346424, 0.466484)), .Names = c("gene", 
 "Species", "labs", "chrMark", "chr", "dN", "dS", "dNdS", "RPKM", 
  "Tau", "GC3"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide the data (`mamals`) you are using? Using `dput`  for example.

Comment: I've added the image of my original dataset on which I use ddply

Comment: Use `dput` instead, something like `dput(head(mydf, 20))` then copy the results into your question as a codeblock.

Comment: I've added that too.

Comment: Looks like you miscopied, the result of `dput` should start with `structure(...`

Comment: I do have a file I made using dput. But the problem is dataset is so large that console does not show the entire result. I have 17009 observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your code and how ggplot handles non-standard evaluation, I'd recommend reading a ggplot tutorial or the docs. Having a column called within `summarised_data` called `'mammals$species'` and `'mammals$chrMark'` is going to cause lots of problems.

If we change these to something more sensible...

```
names(summarised_data)[names(summarised_data) == "mammals$species"] <- "mammals_species"
names(summarised_data)[names(summarised_data) == "mammals$chrMark"] <- "mammals_chrMark"
```

We can make the ggplot code more friendly. Note that shape has to been within `aes`, as you're mapping it to your data.

```
ggplot(summarised_data, aes(x = median_rpkm, y = median)) + 
    geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm") +
    geom_point(aes(shape = mammals_chrMark,
                   color = mammals_species)) +
    xlab("median RPKM") + ylab("dNdS")
```

Hopefully this should work, or at least get you somewhere closer to an answer.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thankyou so much :) I've been banging my head against it for whole day.